# Using Access database with C# on another computer

Tags: c#, .net, oledb, database-connectivity

This feels like a dumb question but I am a bit confused.  I am building a C# address book application (Windows Form) that adds, deletes, selects, and updates contacts to an Access database and I'm using DataGridView in the application to show the contacts.  I follow the easy steps in connecting to an access database using the wizard, which is Add New Data Source --> Database --> DataSet, then for the Data source I use Microsoft Access Database File (OLE DB), and for the Database FileName, I pick a file on my computer, as shown below.

[image]

Now I am confused, because I have to present this on another computer??  Obviously, it won't have the same file address as the one I circled for my computer.  Is there a different way to do this or something, I'm not sure what to do.  I've heard something about mdb files, but I just have to run the executable file on their computers, so I don't know... I use Access 2016, but the computer I am presenting on uses 2013. Thanks

Okay, nevermind.  I found out that I can simply edit the connection string code.  I have to test it once in visual studio, then it works appropriately.

```
     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Chris\Documents\mydb.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";
    }
```

**to**

```
     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\OtherComputer\Desktop\mydb.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put access DB file(.accdb) to your WebSite or Project.

and Database file name :
~/Book_Sample/Access_db1.mdb

If you use Access 2007~2013 (.accdb)
You need to install "Microsoft Access Database Engine Redistributable"

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Oh thanks.  Turns out I implemented a "browse" button with the OpenFileDialog() class and connected the string up as the user chooses.